# jQuery add class to invalid text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Basically I have a table of items like this:

```
<table id="items">
<th>Description</th><th>Qty. In Stock</th><th>Qty. To Issue</th>

<tr><td>description of item</td><td>1</td><td><input type="text" class="qtyissued"></td></tr>


<tr><td>item</td><td>3</td><td><input type="text" class="qtyissued"></td></tr>
</table>
```

The table is in a jQuery modal form. The user enters an amount in the text box of the items to issue from the current quantity in stock. I have validation that stops them entering 0 or more than the available quantity.

What I want to do is add a class to the text box if it contains an invalid number, e.g. 0. I tried doing

```
$('.qtyissued').closest('.qtyissued').addClass('ui-state-error');
$('#items').closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').addClass( "ui-state-error" );
$('.qtyissued').closest('input:text').addClass('ui-state-error');
```

But none of them work, I know I can use `$('.qtyissued).addClass('ui-state-error');` but that will add the class the all the input boxes, even the valid ones.

I am calling the function on click of a button from the modal form, which then calls:

```
var qty = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();
if(qtyissued == "" || qtyissued== 0 || qtyissued> qty) {

$(".qtyissued").each(function(){
    if($(this).val()=='0'){
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-error")
    }
})
        updateError( "Please enter a valid quantity"); //Function to add error message
}
```

Is there a way where I can only add the class to the invalid text boxes.

Comment: can you make jsfiddle pls

Comment: `$('.qtyissued').closest('input:text')` means the closest parent element and inputs cannot have children

Comment: I think, you have the reference of input you are validating for.. So, While validating you can use simply $(<inputreference>).addClass('ui-state-error');

Comment: you want to check it on submit or on value change

Comment: I would suggest you to use onkeyup event and do ur work. $(this).addClass("error") if it doesn't satisfy your requirement.

Comment: I'm doing the validation on click of a button

Comment: @Harry12345 so please fiddle your code so we can understand. Its really confusing for us.

Comment: @Harry12345 http://jsfiddle.net/x612hq84/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would do:

```
$(".qtyissued").each(function(){
    if($(this).val()=='0'){
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-error")
    }
})
```

Comment: this will select each .qtyissued class and check them, just think what if you want to allow 0 on some text box

Comment: it gives opportunity to handle each .qtyissued you can add more classes or attributes to input and handle it just like you want

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work, as `this` refers to the page before I clicked on the modal form. I know this as I using `var desc = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();` which returns a value from the page, not the form

Comment: in this loop i made, `this` points to `.qtyissued` field no matter where it's in code

Comment: I just changed it to `if($(this).val()=='0' || $(this).val() < qty)`, and you missed the `;` after the last bracket